# Using 3d Polyline in QGIS to calculate Volume?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, volume

This question may be completely off the mark. I have a survey drawing in DWG format, I use AutoCAD 2d but the survey was created in LSS.  The Countour lines in the DXF have XYZ coordinates.

Firstly how do i use this layer (i can save it out seperately) in QGIS and how do I display it?

Secondly, is it possible to run a plugin or something (i dont know python) to calculate the volume of this area....

thirdly, i know that the maximum depath of the area is 7m below the highest point. How to create a new layer with the a z coordinate 7 m below maximum height...eg. max height is 110 therefor the z would be 103.

Lastly is any of this possible and am i completely wrong in assuming this can be done?

Any pointers or advice is appriciated.